# VBA-Word: Add line break before all dates in document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a chat log someone pasted in MS Word and gave to me, but in pasting all the carriage returns between chats were stripped off.  Each chat starts with a date in 'MM/DD/YY' format (month can be 1 character only).

I only have access to VBA and I need to insert a new line before each occurrence of a date in order to render this document more human-readable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Wasn't my downvote, but questions tend to be better received if they include an attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without VBA, using find and replace. Ensure "use wildcards" is selected.

- Find: `([0-9/]{7,8})`. This matches 7 or 8 occurrences of a single digit or forward slash. The `()` captures the text for use in the replacement.
- Replace with: `^l\1`. This replaces with a line break character followed by the captured text.

If there's numeric data other than dates, you might need to be a bit more specific with your find string: `([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})`.

Comment: You don't need the () in the Find expression - simply make the Replace ^l^&.